# Separate broker realm to connect an external IdP

Tags: keycloak

I have a multi tenant application which uses keycloak as iam. For each tenant a separate realm is created to separate the tenants as best as possible. The IdP of the customer is connected to each of these realms to enable SSO for the users.
Now, however, employees (2nd level support) of my company should also be able to log on to the realms via SSO. For this purpose, it would actually be possible to connect our Active Directory to each realm. But since I want to avoid this (for various reasons), I would have thought of the following solution.
In Keyclaok a broker realm is created, to which our Active Directory is connected as IdP and which is configured so that all logon attempts are immediately forwarded to the Active Directory. This broker realm is then in turn configured as IdP in each customer realm and thus login via SSO is possible (customer realm -> broker realm -> Active Directory).

Is this a valid solution or do I expect problems here?